# How to find this complexity?

Tags: c, algorithm, big-o, recurrence

If I have a function of the form,

```
int foo ( int n )
{
    if ( n == 0 )
        return 0;
    else
     return n + foo ( n-1)
}
```

Using big-O what is the running time of the call foo(foo(n)).

The recurrence relation is coming  out to be, f(n) = f(n-1) + n, f(0) = 0
And therefore complexity is big-O(n^2). But how to do the above?

Comment: It's not f(n) = f(n-1) + n, but f(n) = f(n-1) + 1 given that addition and setting up the recursive call has cost 1.

Answer (score 5):

> The recurrence relation is coming out to be, f(n) = f(n-1) + n, f(0) = 0 And therefore complexity is big-O(n^2).

Actually, the complexity of the `foo` function is `O(n)`, because you just count down from `n`, call the function with `n - 1` and add the result to `n`.

Now, the **value** returned by `foo` is `O(n^2)`, because the function computes the sum `1 + 2 + ... + n`, which is `n(n+1)/2`.

So, we have:

```
foo(foo(n)) = foo(something that is O(n^2)) = O(n^2)
```

Because the outer `foo` will be linear in its argument, which is `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically you can achieve this using Master Theorem for subtract and conquer recurrences

if T(n) = aT(n-b) + f(n)

for some constants c, a > 0, b > 0, k>= 0 and function f(n). If f(n) is in O(n ^ k) then

then T(n) =

```
        O(n ^ k)       if a < 1

        O(n ^ (k+1))   if a = 1

        O(n^k a^(n/b)) if a > 1
```

Here f(n) = n whose complexity is O(n) therefore k = 1

and a = 1, b = 1

so using second case we can find T(n) = O(n ^ 2)

Answer (score 0):

No. The value that f(n) returns really is O(n^2) but that is not the same thing as the time it takes to compute f. You only need constant time to do an addition operation (add n to the result of f(n-1)) so the real recurrence for time is

```
T(0) = 1
T(n) = 1 + T(n-1)
```

That is, the time it takes to compute f(n) is the time to compute the recursive call plus a constant to add n to that.